# How to specify docstring for __init__ in Python C extension

Tags: python, python-c-api, docstring, python-extensions

Perhaps a stupid question:
how can one specify docstring for special functions like `__init__` when writing a C extension?
For ordinary methods, method table has provision for docstrings. The following autogenerated documentation is displayed when I try help(myclass):

```
  __init__(...)
      x.__init__(...) initializes x; see help(type(x)) for signature
```

But this is what I want to override.

Comment: It's been 10 years, and still no (obvious) solution to this!

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most common thing to do is to just stick the definitions for the various functions into `tp_doc` and just leave it at that.  You can then do as it says and look at your object's doc.  This is what happens all over the standard library.

You don't really have any option of writing `__doc__` on the various slots (`tp_init`, etc.) because they're wrapped by a `wrapper_descriptor` when you call `PyType_Ready`, and the docstring on a `wrapper_descriptor` is read-only.

I think that it is possible to skip using the slots and add your method (e.g. `__init__`) to your `MemberDefs`, but I've never tried that.

Comment: Looks like that is the case. I had already tried putting \_\_init\_\_ in PyMethoDef array. While it does not do any harm to put it there, the interpreter ignores the doc string I provided.